# Xbox One Controller won't connect to Xbox One S

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

My 1 month old xbox one controller won't connect to my xbox one S wirelessly anymore.

Yesterday I was playing FIFA 17 locally against a friend when I had to pause. After pausing my controller disconnected and it would not connect anymore. I tried a lot of things and it looks like it's related to this specific controller and my xbox.

I tried connecting this controller on my macbook via bluetooth and it worked. I tried connecting this controller on my xbox via USB cable and it worked. The other controller is working perfectly with the xbox one, so I think I can rule out it being a console issue.

I've tried everything here:
https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/wireless-controller-disconnects

and a few things on other sites/videos. No luck!

As I said before, after all the testing I've done it seems to be a problem between my xbox one S and that controller. And that is the controller it came bundled with!

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tryed resyncing the controller with the console? It sounds like your controller is paired with your macbook, and cant be paired with the console because of that.

Comment: A couple of times :/

Comment: did you also unpair it with your macbook prior to this? i know from my current bluetooth headphones that if i dont unpair them with my phone, my tablet cant connect to them sometimes.

Comment: no, but the connection to the macbook only occurred after the problem. I was only testing to check whether the controller was still working.

Comment: Im going to assume you have tried most things found online, including a firmware update. In that case i would recommend you contact the support and try get a replacement on warranty, if it still applies

Comment: firmware update for the controller via the xbox one? If so I did and there was no update available. About the warranty, it is still under warranty, but I can't exchange my controller for a new one, maybe it's the region I live in. I tried several times... they open the issue, I get an email to ship the current controller and then the post office label never comes. I've given up...

Comment: Current link is dead, is it similar to [this one](I've tried everything here:
https://beta.support.xbox.com/help/hardware-network/controller/wireless-controller-solution)?

Comment: @rwank +1 I had a similar issue with my controller after connecting to my MacBook. Unpairing from the Macbook then connecting to the Xbox worked. I would suggest posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that you would have to pair the controllers again. By pressing the pairing button and adjusting a specific setting and your controller might work

Comment: What specific setting?